# How do I show database info on my website?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a account page on my website where it shows all information about a user but it does not show the username.

Database Name: df

Table to get info from: members

Column that stores all the usernames: user

Screenshot: [image: https://gyazo.com/e579d7df4eefe856f7f8b2c1fe6425dd]

So I tried this code but it did not work. You may wonder how I came up with that code: I copied the other code that shows when user is registered.

```
echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td align="left" class="padding_td" width="'.$td_width.'">';
                    echo 'Registrerad:';
                echo '</td>';

                echo '<td align="left" class="padding_td">';
                    echo members($user['user']);
                echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
```

When I try this code on my site I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function members() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\account.php on line 328

Here's the code to show when user is registered (may or may not be helpful):

```
echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td align="left" class="padding_td" width="'.$td_width.'">';
                    echo 'Registrerad:';
                echo '</td>';

                echo '<td align="left" class="padding_td">';
                    echo date_detailed($user['date_registred']);
                echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: have you connect database? and fetch data using query?

Comment: Yes, the database is connected @DivyeshSavaliya

Comment: and what about fetch data using query?

Comment: where is your query for fetching up the data from database?

Comment: I don't know, how can i check? I'm a beginner hehe @ShashankShah

Comment: I don't know, how can i check? I'm a beginner hehe @DivyeshSavaliya

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html Go through the link or google might help you as well & by the way echo should be in php tags else it will print echo ''; echo ''; echo 'Registrerad:'; echo ''; echo ''; echo members($user['user']); echo ''; echo ''; as in your snippet

Comment: Where is your `member()` function definition and Which file contain `member()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td align="left" class="padding_td" width="'.$td_width.'">';
echo 'Registrerad:';
echo '</td>';

echo '<td align="left" class="padding_td">';
echo $user['user'];
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```